# How to iterate a function through a list of matrices

Tags: r

I have a folder full of csv files that I have read and turned into matrices.

```
setwd("~/Desktop/EMD Test")
FilesToProcess <- list.files(pattern = "csv")     
listOfFiles <- lapply(FilesToProcess, function(x){ out = read.csv(x, header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) as.matrix(out) })
```

Now I need to do an EMD calculation comparing all the files to the first one. Manually it looks like this:

```
emd(listOfFles[[1]],listOfFiles[[2]])
```

What I would like to do is run this command with all the files in ListOfFIles like

```
emd(listOfFles[[1]],listOfFiles[[x]])
```

I have tried several things with lapply and for loops but nothing has worked.

Comment: I think lapply should work. What's your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a nested `lapply` if we want to do the pairwise `emd` on all combinations of `list` elements

```
lapply(seq_along(listOfFles), function(i) lapply(seq_along(ListOfFles),
        function(j) emd(listOfFles[[i]], listOfFles[[j]])))
```

---

Or another option is `combn` which could be more efficient because the number of combinations are reduced

```
combn(ListOfFles, 2, FUN = function(x) emd(x[[1]], x[[2]]), simplify = FALSE)
```

Comment: The lapply worked. The "seq_along" is what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare the first file with all other files. You can use `for` loop in this way.

```
FilesToProcess <- list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$")
result <- vector('list', length(FilesToProcess) - 1)

for(i in 2:length(FilesToProcess)) {
  result[[i]] <- emd(listOfFles[[1]],listOfFiles[[i]])
}
```